# Airflow task stuck : Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run

Tags: airflow

I have looked at other stack overflow posts for this similar issue but am still unable to find the root cause.

Basically I have a task that executes a PL/SQL script. It gets stuck and will be running indefinitely; then I have to clear it (*twice!*) in order for it to actually run.

Once it actually runs it only takes ~30 seconds.

I need this to work on the first try so that it is fully automated. Is there a workaround or any additional insight as to why this can occur?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue
https://forum.astronomer.io/t/scheduler-freezing-hanging-without-a-trace/365

sometimes scheduler hangs

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could show how this answers the Question.